# How to find Code generating known data?

Tags: reverse-engineering

From debugging the program I only know that before clicking a button a set of known data isn't in memory (confirmed by memory search) and after clicking it the data is in memory (all the time a different location).

How can I find the code that generates this data?

One of the major problems (which might be important to know) is that it is a .net-Program (which I can't analyze with Reflector because it is obfuscated). So I'm analyzing the assembly generated by .NET (in Olly / Immunity / IDA).

Answer (score 0):

If it is .Net you could debug the [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code. It is not easy though, but it should be possible to find the il intruction that writes the sequence into memory.

Try [debugging tools for windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063.aspx) with the so called [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) extension.

You could also try if it would be possible to generate say C# code from the obfuscated assemblies for debugging. But this will most certainly not better readable code than IL.

Comment: Can't I somehow just find the assembly instructions generated by the .NET-Framework that generate my preknown data?

Comment: I do not know such a method. The only way I can think of is debugging the code starting from the method handling the button click event if you can find this point in the il.

Comment: Debugging through that code is nearly impossible, because .NET generates lots of code. I tried instruction traceing for the button click and stopped it after 8h so thats pretty much not doable.

Answer (score 0):

Add Cheat Engine to your toolkit.

If you can get the address it will write to you could right click it and choose "Find out what writes to this address".

*P.S. For a reverse effect you can select an instruction in the memory view, right click and choose "Find out what addresses this instruction access".*